# Authorize Attribute with multiple Roles asp.net

Tags: asp.net

It seem like i can't have both roles. if i use only "administrator" its works and if only "advisor" it also works but not work with when i code both of them so any idea or help? i need both roles

here is my code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ' Check that the user is a registered user
    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = False Then
        Response.Redirect("Unauthorized.aspx")
    End If

    ' Check that the user belongs to the role Administrators
    If Roles.IsUserInRole("administrator") = False Then
        Response.Redirect("Unauthorized.aspx")
    End If

    ' Check that the user belongs to the role Advisor
    'If Roles.IsUserInRole("advisor") = False Then
    '    Response.Redirect("Unauthorized.aspx")
    'End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You can use logical 'OR' operator: `If Not Roles.IsUserInRole("administrator") Or Not Roles.IsUserInRole("advisor") Then...`. Also you may don't compare logical values with `False` or `True`, f.e.: `If Not User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then ...`.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko i did it as you just comment and still doesn't work but thanks for let me try

Comment: It's cause I gave incorrect answer, sorry. Correct answer is: use **logical AND** operator. Negate for *user is administrator or user is advisor* is *user isn't administrator and user isn't advisor*, so your code should be `If Not Roles.IsUserInRole("administrator") And Not Roles.IsUserInRole("advisor") Then ...`.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Thanks you for your help..  now it works fine